# How to query all the tables in a database to get the last existing value?

Tags: mysql

I've got several databases in which every table contains data from energy-meters, structure is always like that:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| dsid | tag | timestamp  | value   | startts    | correctts  | isfixed |
=========================================================================
|  1   | EE  | 1444716843 | 519.193 | 1444716000 | 1444716900 | 0       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2   | PO  | 1444716843 | 0.090   | 1444716000 | 1444716900 | 0       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  3   | EE  | 1444717743 | 519.216 | 1444716900 | 1444717800 | 0       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

using the following code I can read the last existing value in one table:

```
SELECT
  from_unixtime(TIMESTAMP) AS DATE,
  VALUE 
FROM `KA-AIK_Labor`
WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('19-03-19') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('19-03-31 23:59:59')
ORDER BY DSID DESC LIMIT 1
```

What I'ld like to achieve is an output like the following:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| dsid | TABELNAME    | DATE                | VALUE      |
==========================================================
| 1    | KA-AIK_Labor | 2019-03-25 10:30:23 | 360884.000 |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 2    | KA-AIK_1. OG | 2019-03-25 10:44:00 | 12251.334  |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I've already got some code to get a list of all tables in my Database:

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA='KAAIK'
```

But with my little SQL Experience I don't know how to incorporate that code into one...

And additionally I'ld love to read all the tables into one like that:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| dsid | DATE                | TABELNAME#1  | VALUE#1    | TABELNAME#1  | VALUE#1   |
=====================================================================================
| 1    | 2019-03-25 10:30:23 | KA-AIK_Labor | 360884.000 | KA-AIK_1. OG | 12251.315 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2    | 2019-03-25 10:45:17 | KA-AIK_Labor | 360884.010 | KA-AIK_1. OG | 12251.325 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've the following code:

```
SELECT
  from_unixtime(TIMESTAMP) AS DATE,
  VALUE 
FROM `KA-AIK_1. OG`
WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('19-03-24') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('19-03-24 11:59:59')
```

to read a list like this:

```
-----------------------------------
| DATE                | VALUE     |
===================================
| 2019-03-25 10:30:23 | 12251.315 |
-----------------------------------
| 2019-03-25 10:45:17 | 12251.325 |
-----------------------------------
```

But again I can't find out how to transform/modify my code..

Comment: @GMB THX was about to make the same change...

Comment: I see two options: 1) Use dynamic SQL to assemble a gigantic SQL at runtime, based on the tables existing in the database. 2) Create a stored procedure in MySQL that gets the list of tables and runs the same query one by one on each one in order to finally assemble a single result set (probably using a `TEMPORARY` table.